# Using turtle module exitonclick()

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My code should close the turtle.screen after first part then start another screen and do the second part. but there it is not working as intend.

```
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()
tod_1 = turtle.Turtle()
tod_1.color("red", "green")
tod_1.begin_fill()
for i in range(3):
    tod_1.forward(50)
    tod_1.left(360 / 3)
tod_1.end_fill()
ws.exitonclick()

input("go'press any thing' ")

ws = turtle.Screen()
tod_2 = turtle.Turtle()
tod_2.color("red", "green")
tod_2.begin_fill()
for i in range(6):
    tod_2.forward(50)
    tod_2.left(360 / 6)
tod_2.end_fill()
ws.exitonclick()
```

the first part works fine but I get this after the input():

```
go'press any thing' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    tod_2 = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\itt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "C:\Users\itt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\itt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\itt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\itt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

I tried to clear all variables using:

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()
```

then import turtle again and do the sec. part, but without success.

Comment: and what you get? Do you run it in IDLE ?

Comment: Is it halting all execution or is it behaving in another unexpected way? "not working as intend" doesn't tell us what you're seeing.

Comment: it executes the first part with no problem

Comment: Your code works ok in Python 2.6 (using `raw_input` instead of `input`), but not on Python 3.6.

Comment: Why do you want to close the Turtle screen & then open a new one? Why not just reset the original screen?

Comment: @PM2Ring do you have any idea why?

Comment: Note that turtle (and other Tkinter code) may behave slightly differently in IDLE compared to in the normal terminal because IDLE is itself a Tkinter program.

Comment: you can use `import turtle ; print(turtle.__file__)` to find file with source code. And you will see in source code, that `exitonclick()` removes from memory not only `Screen()` - it was created to end program.

Comment: I don't know why it no longer works in Python 3, but furas's theory sounds good to me. `exitonclick()` probably destroys important objects & state information. Also, I assume that `turtle.Screen()` opens a Tkinter root window, and it's _never_ a good idea to open more than one of those in a Tkinter program. My guess is that the old Python 2 turtle module lets you get away with it, but it really shouldn't have. :) But as I said, I'm only guessing: I know a bit about Tkinter, and although I've written a handful of turtle programs I've never investigated its inner workings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when `turtle` is imported it creates many objects and `exitonclick()` removes all of them - not only `Screen()`. `exitonclick()` was created to end program.

But you can use `oscreenclick(function_name)` to assign function to mouse click which will clear screen and draw next object. `onscreenclick` execute function with two arguments - position of click - so function has to receive this information.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def second(x, y): 
    # clear screen
    tod.reset()

    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(6):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 6)
        tod.end_fill()

    # run another function on click
    #turtle.onscreenclick(third)

    # end program on click 
    turtle.exitonclick()

# --- main ---

tod = turtle.Turtle()

tod.color("red", "green")
tod.begin_fill()
for i in range(3):
    tod.forward(50)
    tod.left(360 / 3)
    tod.end_fill()

# assign function to click on screen
turtle.onscreenclick(second)

# you need it to - it checks if you clicked (and does othere things)
turtle.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** if you have to remove window and show again than you can use `tod._screen._root` to get access to main window which use `tkinter`, and you can hide/show it

```
tod._screen._root.iconify()   # hide
input("Press Enter: ")
tod._screen._root.deiconify() # show again
```

Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import turtle

# --- functions ---

def stop(callback):

    #tod._screen._root.attributes("-topmost", False)

    tod._screen._root.iconify()
    # upper Y in text means that it will be default answer if you press only Enter
    answer = input("Show more images? [Y/n]: ").strip().lower()
    if not answer: # empty string treat as `Y`
        answer = 'y'
    tod._screen._root.deiconify()

    # problem with moving window above other windows
    #tod._screen._root.lift()
    tod._screen._root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    #tod._screen._root.update()

    if answer == 'y':
        callback()
    else:
        #turtle.exitonclick()
        # or
        turtle.bye()

def first(x=0, y=0):
    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 3)
        tod.end_fill()

    # assign function to click on screen
    turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x,y:stop(second))

def second(x=0, y=0):
    # clear screen
    tod.reset()

    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(6):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 6)
        tod.end_fill()

    # assign function to click on screen
    turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x,y:stop(third))

def third(x=0, y=0):
    # clear screen
    tod.reset()

    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(12):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 12)
        tod.end_fill()

    # end program on click
    turtle.exitonclick()

# --- main ---

tod = turtle.Turtle()

first()

# you need it to - it checks if you clicked (and does othere things)
turtle.mainloop()
```

But instead of `input()` you can use `tkinter` and its messageboxes

```
answer = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('More?', "Show more images?")
```

Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import turtle
import tkinter.messagebox

# --- functions ---

def stop(callback):

    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('More?', "Show more images?")
    print('answer:', answer)

    if answer:
        callback()
    else:
        #turtle.exitonclick()
        # or
        turtle.bye()

def first(x=0, y=0):
    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 3)
        tod.end_fill()

    # assign function to click on screen
    turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x,y:stop(second))

def second(x=0, y=0):
    # clear screen
    tod.reset()

    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(6):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 6)
        tod.end_fill()

    # assign function to click on screen
    turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x,y:stop(third))

def third(x=0, y=0):
    # clear screen
    tod.reset()

    tod.color("red", "green")
    tod.begin_fill()
    for i in range(12):
        tod.forward(50)
        tod.left(360 / 12)
        tod.end_fill()

    # end program on click
    turtle.exitonclick()

# --- main ---

tod = turtle.Turtle()

first()

# you need it to - it checks if you clicked (and does othere things)
turtle.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** I checked source code of `turtle` and it seems that you can set

```
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

to run `turtle` again after `exitonclick()`

Try this code with and without `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True`

```
import turtle

turtle.goto(0,50)
turtle.exitonclick()

turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True

turtle.goto(50,150)
turtle.exitonclick()

turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

But maybe with more complex code it will not work because `exitonclick()` does other things - oryginal function which is executed by `exitonclick()`

```
def _destroy(self):
    root = self._root
    if root is _Screen._root:
        Turtle._pen = None
        Turtle._screen = None
        _Screen._root = None
        _Screen._canvas = None
    TurtleScreen._RUNNING = False
    root.destroy()
```

Comment: isn't there any way to to exit the screen and reopen it?

Comment: there is no method to do it. But turtle uses `tkinter` and you can have access to it and to main window `tod._screen._root` and hide it `tod._screen._root.iconify()` and show again `tod._screen._root.deiconify()`

Comment: see new code with `tod._screen._root.iconify()` and with `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('More?', "Show more images?")`

Comment: I tried to clear all variables using: `sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()` and use `import turtle` again but got the same result

Comment: try `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True` - see example in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added one line to your code so that the turtle class gets reimported and in the next initialization the class variable turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING will be set to true.

Working Code:

```
import importlib
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()
tod_1 = turtle.Turtle()
tod_1.color("red", "green")
tod_1.begin_fill()
for i in range(3):
    tod_1.forward(50)
    tod_1.left(360 / 3)
tod_1.end_fill()
ws.exitonclick()

importlib.reload(turtle)
input("go'press any thing' ")

ws = turtle.Screen()
tod_2 = turtle.Turtle()
tod_2.color("red", "green")
tod_2.begin_fill()
for i in range(6):
    tod_2.forward(50)
    tod_2.left(360 / 6)
tod_2.end_fill()
ws.exitonclick()
```