# How to Close Python Turtle Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

When I run my python program from terminal it will run fine. It uses turtle to do draw an image in a while loop.

If I close the program after the while loop has finsished and then try and run it again it throws an error but if I run it again after that it works fine

Bur if I close the program whilst it is still in the while loop it will throw the error and then when I try to run it again it will run fine

My guess is that turtle is not closing properly but every way of stopping it doesn't do anything

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tristan/Documents/Python/Orbit/orbit.py", line 16, in orbit
    t.goto(xPos,yPos)
  File "<string>", line 5, in goto
turtle.Terminator
```

My code:

```
import turtle as t
import time
import math

def orbit(y):
    xPos = 0
    yPos = y

    while (yPos < 15) :

        t.goto(xPos,yPos)
        yPos += 1

    time.sleep(0.005)

t.exitonclick()
```

Comment: show code. How do you close it ? You have `exitonclick` and similar functions to end script. It should stop `mainloop` correctly.

Comment: Yeah I have that but it doesn't work

Comment: we can't help you without your code. Theoretically it should stop but code can be incorrect constructed and you can do something what you shouldn't do.

Comment: There, I've put it up

Comment: you have function `orbit` but you don't run it so it does nothing - how could you get error in `t.goto(xPos,yPos)` ?

Comment: I run it in terminal with orbit.orbit(5)

Comment: In python3 then importing the module

Comment: what terminal ?

Comment: don't you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe using `python script.py` ?

Comment: The Ubuntu unity one

Comment: you run python (so called "Python Shell" or "Python REPL" or "Python in interactive mode") and then you run it again and again - but `t.exitonclick()` remove from memery many objects and `turtle` can't run correctly. Even if you import file again it may not work. Normal method to run code is `python script.py`

Comment: No, I open up pyhton3 in terminal, then import the module and then run the function

Comment: `turtle` doesn't expect that it will be executed this way - it expects that after `t.exitonclick()` Python will be closed so `t.exitonclick()` remove some objects from memory and `turtle` can't run without this objects and it shows error `turtle.Terminator`

Comment: Ah okay thanks, that makes sense, if you write that as an answer I'll mark it as an answer

Comment: yesterday was question with similar problem - solution was to force Python to import turtle again. Normally Python remeber what files was imported and doesn't import again the same file when you use again `import turtle`

Comment: see last comment on: [using-turtle-module-exitonclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548813/using-turtle-module-exitonclick) but I didn't check it if it realy works

Answer (score 2):

`exitonclick()` removes from memory some objects which normally `turtle` needs to work - so if you try to run in terminal/"Python Shell" any turlte command after `exitonclick()` then you get error `turtle.Terminator`.

`exitonclick()` expects that after `exitonclick()` Python will be closed and `turtle` doesn't need this object.

Maybe if you could force Python to import again `turtle` module then maybe it could work again (but normally Python remember imported modules and doesn't import again when you do again `import turtle`)

---

**EDIT:** I checked source code of `turtle` and it seems that you can set

```
  turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

to run `turtle` again after `exitonclick()`

Try this code with and without `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True`

```
import turtle as t

t.goto(0,50)
t.exitonclick()

t.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True

t.goto(50,150)
t.exitonclick()

t.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
```

But maybe with more complex code it will not work because `exitonclick()` does other things - oryginal function which is executed by `exitonclick()`

```
def _destroy(self):
    root = self._root
    if root is _Screen._root:
        Turtle._pen = None
        Turtle._screen = None
        _Screen._root = None
        _Screen._canvas = None
    TurtleScreen._RUNNING = False
    root.destroy()
```