# Python turtle terminator error on alternating runs

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have the following code running in anaconda spyder:

```
from turtle import *

speed(0)
setup(800, 700)

#Blue Background
penup()
goto(0, -320)
pendown()
color("lightskyblue")
begin_fill()
circle(320)
end_fill()
done()
```

on the second run and every other (run 4, run 6 ...) I get the following message in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\robert\downloads\mit python\pset4\problemset4\snowman.py:9
    speed(0)

  File <string>:5 in speed

Terminator
```

on runs 1, 3, 5... I get the expected output

If I add bye() as last line I get on even runs the following message in console:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Robert/Downloads/MIT python/pset4/ProblemSet4/snowman.py', wdir='C:/Users/Robert/Downloads/MIT python/pset4/ProblemSet4')

Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread


Windows fatal exception: code 0x80000003


Main thread:
Thread 0x00001c64 (most recent call first):
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 262 in _remote_callback
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\commbase.py", line 343 in _handle_remote_call
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\commbase.py", line 333 in _comm_message
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 256 in handle_msg
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\comm\base_comm.py", line 263 in comm_msg
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 410 in dispatch_shell
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 505 in process_one
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 516 in dispatch_queue
  File "E:\python\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80 in _run
  File "E:\python\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1922 in _run_once
  File "E:\python\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607 in run_forever
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 195 in start
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 736 in start
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 330 in main
  File "E:\python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24 in <module>
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88 in _run_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198 in _run_module_as_main


Restarting kernel...
 
%pylab is deprecated, use %matplotlib inline and import the required libraries.
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
```

So, after I get the error message it restarts the kernel and populates the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib.  Then when I run again it works, but if I run it again I get the above message and restarts the kernel

Comment: I don't know anything about Anaconda/Spyder, but why is state being persisted between runs? That shouldn't be happening--each process ("run") should be totally idempotent. Terminator errors occur when you try to call a turtle operation when it's already been destroyed.

Comment: I have no idea.  this was a clean reinstall of anaconda

Comment: do you run it as `python script.py` or in `IPython` or `Jupyter`? As I know `turtle` destroys some elements at the end and you can't run it again in the same script or interpreter - you have to reload all again (and this means to restart python)

Comment: I found this problem in [How to Close Python Turtle Properly - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644324/how-to-close-python-turtle-properly/41644914#41644914) and `turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True`

Comment: Setting the internal property is a workaround that shouldn't be necessary (but is nice to know about to unblock OP until a true solution is found).