# The error "turtle.Terminator" occurs when using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have created a function which uses the turtle module in python:

```
def printmaze(sizeX, sizeY, walls):

    startX = -300
    startY = 300

    high = (-startX // sizeX) * 2
    width = (startY // sizeY) * 2

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-startX, -startY)
    turtle.goto(startX, -startY)

    turtle.setheading(0)
    for i in range(sizeX):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX, startY - high * i)
        for l in range(sizeY):
            if walls[i][l][1] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.right(90)
    for i in range(sizeY):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX  + width * i, startY)
        for l in range(sizeX):

            if walls[l][i][0] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(high)
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.exitonclick()
```

When I execute this function for the first time, there is no error. However, when I execute it for the second time, it returns turtle.Terminator. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using turtle module exitonclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548813/using-turtle-module-exitonclick)

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your response, it indeed resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turtle uses a variable called `_RUNNING` which becomes false when `.exitonclick()` is called. So, you need to call `turtle.Screen()` at the beginning and call `.exitonclick()` at the end of the program. Both of them should be called outside the function. Modified code:

```
#Import necessary modules
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen() #At beginning outside function

#Create the function to draw the maze
def printmaze(sizeX, sizeY, walls):
    startX = -300
    startY = 300

    high = (-startX // sizeX) * 2
    width = (startY // sizeY) * 2

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-startX, -startY)
    turtle.goto(startX, -startY)

    turtle.setheading(0)
    for i in range(sizeX):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX, startY - high * i)
        for l in range(sizeY):
            if walls[i][l][1] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.right(90)
    for i in range(sizeY):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX  + width * i, startY)
        for l in range(sizeX):

            if walls[l][i][0] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(high)

screen.exitonclick() #At the end outside the function
```

You need to call `screen = turtle.Screen()` and `.exitonclick()` only once in your program. There is no need to call them every time the function is called. So, you need to put them outside the function.

**Edit:**

If the above method doesn't work, then you can manually set the `_RUNNING` variable to true after `.exitonclick()` is called. Modified code:

```
#Import necessary modules
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen() #At beginning outside function

#Create the function to draw the maze
def printmaze(sizeX, sizeY, walls):
    startX = -300
    startY = 300

    high = (-startX // sizeX) * 2
    width = (startY // sizeY) * 2

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-startX, -startY)
    turtle.goto(startX, -startY)

    turtle.setheading(0)
    for i in range(sizeX):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX, startY - high * i)
        for l in range(sizeY):
            if walls[i][l][1] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.right(90)
    for i in range(sizeY):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX  + width * i, startY)
        for l in range(sizeX):

            if walls[l][i][0] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(high)

screen.exitonclick() #At the end outside the function

turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True #Set the _RUNNING variable to true
```

Comment: I still encountered the same issue even after using this method

Comment: @Loger You need to call `screen = turtle.Screen()` and `.exitonclick()` only once in your program. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I did try it indeed, but it still doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: @Loger Then you can manually set the `_RUNNING` variable to true. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create the Screen at the beginning and exitonclick needs to be outside the function:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
def printmaze(sizeX, sizeY, walls):

    startX = -300
    startY = 300

    high = (-startX // sizeX) * 2
    width = (startY // sizeY) * 2

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-startX, -startY)
    turtle.goto(startX, -startY)

    turtle.setheading(0)
    for i in range(sizeX):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX, startY - high * i)
        for l in range(sizeY):
            if walls[i][l][1] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.right(90)
    for i in range(sizeY):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(startX  + width * i, startY)
        for l in range(sizeX):

            if walls[l][i][0] ==  1:
                turtle.pendown()
            else:
                turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(high)
screen.exitonclick()
```